# iPhone 4s on iOS8.1 and iPhone 6 are loading the same image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, autolayout

I set different images for all sizes to see if images are loading correctly or not.

[image]

I figured out that iphone simulator 4s with iOS7.1 does not load the same image compared to the simulator 4s with iOS8.1

In fact the iphone 4s simulator(iOS8.1) is loading the same image loaded by the iphone 6 simulator which is bigger than the suitable one.

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Is that causing a problem? What are you trying to fix? What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: Yes because the image for the iPhone 6 is bigger than the one for the iPhone 4, so it is being loaded so much bigger than it is supposed to be.

Comment: Ok. You confused me now. So what is the screenshot of? That doesn't look like the asset catalog screen in Xcode. Also, why do you have so many different versions? Also, are you using ios6 or not? The title says it isn't the same on ios6?

Comment: Might cause problems if ones layout depends on the size of the images from the resources, if you can reliably reproduce it, even only with a simulator, better to submit a bug report. @Fogmeister it's a bit mixed up, but I believe the iPhone 4s simulator loads higher res images than it should: the same as iPhone 6 is supposed to use.

Comment: @Fogmeister it is exactly like  A-Live said.
Iphone 4s simulator is loading iphone 6 simulator images. You see the problem??

Comment: You think it is a simulator bug?? the other thing to notice i that iphone 4s simulator on iOS7.1 is loading the correct image but on iOS8.1 it is loading iphone 6 image

Comment: The iPhone 4S and the iPhone 6 *should* load the same image: -at-2x. It's only the IPhone 6+ that uses the -at-3x images. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html Also, "the image for the iPhone 6 is bigger than the one for the iPhone 4, so it is being loaded so much bigger than it is supposed to be" is confusing-- @A-Live notes you should not be using this to make an image "bigger" for the iPhone 6. The screen resolution has 2- or 3-times more pixels, so it will be more detailed but appear the same size in inches on scre

Comment: @MichaelSand do have any idea why iphone 4s iOS7.1  and 4s iOS8.1 simulators are not loading the same image??

Comment: For "any idea" and not a definitive answer, presumably image-loading handling was changed in iOS8 to accommodate the 6+ -at-3x images. Also, although easier said than done if you don't have devices lying around (I'm independent so I know), for things like this where you're trying to debug device-and-version inconsistencies, the debugging really needs to be on actual devices running actual versions, the simulators are not guaranteed to act consistently.